# incrementing version number in a subdocument and the parent document

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to add versioning levels in a document as well as its subdocuments. Heres a schema example

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d1312a8ee6de1858933950"),
    "synonyms" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59d1312a8ee6de1858933954"),
            "text" : [ 
                1.0, 
                2.0, 
                3.0
            ],
            "__v" : 1.0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59d1312a8ee6de1858933953"),
            "text" : [ 
                "Foo ", 
                "bar ", 
                "Baz"
            ],
            "__v" : 0
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59d1312a8ee6de1858933951"),
            "text" : [ 
                "fizz", 
                "bazz", 
                "bizz"
            ],
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 3.0
}
```

As you can see , the parent document has its own `__v` while each subdocument (part of the synonyms array) also has its `__v` . What i'm trying to accomplish is this

- When updating a subdocument array - increment the version of the subdocument as well as its parent version

to that effect , i've tried the below code

```
db.collection.update({
    '_id': ObjectId("59d1312a8ee6de1858933950"),
    "synonyms._id": ObjectId("59d1312a8ee6de1858933954")
},
    {$set: {'synonyms.$.text': [1,2,3]}, $inc: {'synonyms.$.__v': 1}, $inc: {"__v": 1}}
)
```

My parent `__v` is getting increment on every update but the subdocument seems to be stuck at `1.0` no matter how many updates i go through. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about the parameters that you pass to a MongoDB command as a JSON document rather than a string this makes perfect sense: Passing in the same operator twice (as in `$inc` at the start and later another `$inc` again in your example) will create a JSON document that only contains the last parameter. This would be different if you were using a string here which would actually represent a JSON document with two `$inc` fields.

So here's how to get it right (basically by [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/index.html)ing two fields as part of a single operation):

```
db.collection.update({
    '_id': ObjectId("59d1312a8ee6de1858933950"),
    "synonyms._id": ObjectId("59d1312a8ee6de1858933954")
},
    {$set: {'synonyms.$.text': [1,2,3]}, $inc: {'synonyms.$.__v': 1, "__v": 1}}
)
```